# tabularx table not taking page width after importing ltablex

Tags: tables, tabularx, textwidth, ltablex

I want some tables to take up the page width. I was able to do this using the `tabularx` package and the `X` parameter.

Here is an example of what a table looks like:

[image: table with tabularx alone]

However, I need to use captions but I also want to use them with a `tabularx` table. I used the `ltablex` package and captions work. However, after importing them tables no longer take the full page width. Tables look something like this after importing `ltablex`:

[image: table after importing ltablex]

I've already tried using `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` but I still get the same result. I couldn't find a solution to the problem.

**Code Sample:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}

\begin{document}
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    Heading 1 & Heading 2\\
    \hline\hline
    Lorem ipsum & Dolor sit\\
    \hline
    Amet consectetuer & Adipiscing elit\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use the `ltablex` package? Do you want to use `X` columns in tables that are longer than a page? If so, try `xltabular` instead. Your comment "However, I need to use captions but I also want to use them with a tabluarx table. I used the ltablex package and captions work." makes me wonder if you just added `ltablex` for the captions. If that's the case, please keep in mind that you could just place the `tabularx` table inside of a `table` environment and use `\caption` there.

Comment: I didn't know I could wrap the `tabularx` inside a `table`. That solved my problem Thanks!

Comment: Any tabular-like environment that is not supposed to span multiple pages can be placed inside of `table`.

Comment: Oh alright, thanks for the help @leandriis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is caused by the following feature of the `ltablex` package: (Quoted from the package manual)

> Another feature that has been added is to treat the `X` columns like `l`
> columns if the table contents would allow that to happen without
> exceeding the specified width of the table. In other words, the
> specified width is treated as the maximum allowed and not the exact
> width of the table. This feature is the default but can be disabled
> (or enabled) with `\keepXColumns` (or `\convertXColumns`).

---

Since the actual question is "How to add a caption to a `tabularx` environment", here is a comment on that, as well. Just place the `tabularx` in a `table` environment and use the `\caption` command there.

Comment: Thanks for the help!